# Profile Image does not change - PHP + Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm trying to create a Profile picture change using PHP and JQuery, but i have a problem.

I'm trying to do this, on change a image on `file input`, i send it to my server, and change the `src` of my `<img>` , but works only on the first time, after this my `src` doesn't change.

The image upload is working, only the image refresh does not works

Heres my code:

**HTML:**

```
<img src="./image_path/profile.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Change profile image" class="border rounded-circle img-user-profile">
<input id="file-upload" type="file" name="file-upload" id="file-upload" />
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#file-upload").change(function() {
        img($(this).closest('form'))
    });
});


function img(e) {
    let event = e[0]

    let formData = new FormData(event);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './dataProcess/UpTempImg.php', // Here i upload a image to a temporary folder
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $(".img-user-profile").attr('src', "./imagens/loading.svg")

        },
        success: function(data) {
            // data returns a image path
            // Example: https://mysite.com.br/images/temp/user_image.png
            $(".img-user-profile").attr('src', data)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to do basic debugging first. Find out what part of your code runs, and what is stored in your variables. The very first thing you should do is `console.log(data)` in your success callback.

Comment: I did it, my data is correct, so the first time works correctly

Comment: Maybe this tutorial will help you: https://makitweb.com/how-to-upload-image-file-using-ajax-and-jquery/

Comment: What does happen if you make img(event)? What do you get if you make console.log('form',img($(this).closest('form')))?

Comment: Every time i change the image, i need to POST the form, so i receive the form using .closest()